# Python: await the generator end

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, generator, coroutine

Current versions of Python (Dec 2022) still allow using @coroutine decorator and a generation can be as:

```
import asyncio
asyncify = asyncio.coroutine
data_ready = False # Status of a pipe, just to test

def gen():
    global data_ready

    while not data_ready:
        print("not ready")
        data_ready = True # Just to test
        yield

    return "done"

async def main():
    result = await asyncify(gen)()
    print(result)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

However, new Python versions 3.8+ will deprecate @coroutine decorator (the `asyncify` function alias), **how to wait for (await) generator to end as above**?

I tried to use `async def` as expected by the warning but not working:

```
import asyncio
asyncify = asyncio.coroutine
data_ready = False # Just to test

async def gen():
    global data_ready

    while not data_ready:
        print("not ready")
        data_ready = True # Just to test
        yield

    yield "done"
    return

async def main():
    # this has error: TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression
    result = await gen()
    print(result)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Those two code samples show very different things. The first is an awaitable coroutine, the second is an asynchronous generator. Neither is suitable to "to wait for (await) generator to end" because neither awaits a generator. What exactly are you trying to do? What should the generator yield *to,* and what should it yield? In other words, why do you want a generator in the first place?

Comment: Manually using `yield` in an `asyncio.coroutine`-marked generator is an extremely unusual thing to do anywhere outside the `asyncio` core itself - I don't think the semantics of doing that are actually part of the `asyncio` public API.

Comment: im trying to poll until data ready and not to block main thread, the first sample is for that purpose. The 2nd sample is just a try to convert to `async def` to replace the deprecated @coroutine decorator

Comment: (Also, `asyncio.coroutine` has *already* been deprecated since 3.8, and *already* been removed in 3.11.)

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for `asyncio.sleep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Asynchronous generators** inherit *asynchronous iterator* and are aimed for asynchronous iterations. 
You can not directly `await` them as regular coroutines.
With that in mind, returning to your experimental case and your question *"how to wait for (await) generator to end?"*: to get the final `yield`ed value - perform asynchronous iterations:

```
import asyncio

data_ready = False # Just to test

async def gen():
    global data_ready
    while not data_ready:
        print("not ready")
        data_ready = True # Just to test
        yield "processing"
    yield "done"
    return


async def main():
    a_gen = gen()
    async for result in a_gen:  # assign to result on each async iteration
        pass
    print('result:', result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
not ready
result: done
```

---

Naturally, you can also advance the *async* generator in steps with `anext`:

```
a_gen = gen()
val_1 = await anext(a_gen)
```

---

Summing up, follow the guidlines on [PEP 525 – Asynchronous Generators](https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/) and try to not mix *old-depreceted* things with the actual ones.

Comment: tks, a found a similar solution too `await a_gen.asend(None)` :) on python <3.10